# Querying with data from multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i have MySQL database **db1** with data of user and it managers, and **db2** with oter data related to user, but without user manager column. 
I need to query db2 and group data by user manager.

if they were on same server that would be easy.

do you have any suggestion how to do this, even on non query fashion?

NOTE: **db1** and **db2** are not on same server, and query will not contain just simple sums

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried. The logic says that you would query both and then while looping through results from one compare it to the other.

Comment: I did not try anything yet, just discussing about ways to do so. Yes, one solution is to query both sides, and then do the loop in app (PHP), and the other one in my opinion is to query one side and build in result into query for other side. Which one would be better (faster), because data in db2 are huuuge :)

Comment: SO is not the place for that kind of discussion, you may want to try http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use federated tables in MySQL, and it will let you access data from a remote MySQL database

You can check out this on given links below

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-create-server.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-limitations.html

I guess it may work for you.

Happy Coding!

Atul Jindal